# Model.save throws 404 error on Android

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, backbone.js

I have an app that uses `Backbone.js`, I build this app using Cordova. The app does a login request and this works fine on iOS and on the web browser so I know the method is present and working. However, for Android it returns a "POST 404 (Not found)" error, even that the code is the same. Why is it working on iOS and not on Android? Would it be a code issue or a build issue?

This is my request:

```
return $.ajax(params);

//params
Object {headers: Object, type: "POST", dataType: "json", data: "
{"email":"username@domain.com","password":"password"}"…}
crossDomain :true
data :"{"email":"username@domain.com","password":"password"}"
dataType :"json"
error :function (resp)
headers: Object
  Accept : "*/*; charset=utf-8"
Content-Type :"application/json"
isLoginRequest: true
parse: true
processData: false
success: function (resp)
type :"POST"
url :"http://ip_address:port/api/login"
validate: true
__proto__ :Object

//method
var context, errors = [], model = new Model({}, {url: Config.login});
        model.set(data);
        if(!model.isValid()){
            context = _.extend({
                errors: model.validationError
            }, data);
            this.renderLoginView(context);
            return;
        }
        model.save(null, {
            isLoginRequest: true,
            success: _.bind(this.loginSuccess, this),
            error: _.bind(function(xhr, textStatus){
                //this is where it goes
                errors = {name: 'email/password', message: 'Invalid Username or Password'};
                context = _.extend({
                    errors: errors
                }, data);
                this.renderLoginView(context);
            },this)
        });
```

Comment: are you sure you are using correct IP? Is it real IP address, or local address?

Comment: It's the correct IP address, the same code works ok on iOS

Comment: maybe iOS is connected to the internet another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the Cordova Whitelist plugin installed.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

This is required for Android and not on iOS or Browser.

Then check your config.xml for lines like these.

```
<access origin="*"/>
```

This will allow any network communication from your app. To be more safe you can change this to.

```
<access origin="YOUR_URL/*" />
```

This will allow network access only the the URL specified and any subdomains.

See the documentation here.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/

Comment: There are no words in this world to express my gratitude to you, I have been fighting with this issue for a couple of days. Installing that plugin did the trick! Thanks again

Comment: No problem I have struggled with whitelist issues in the past myself. Glad to help.